# Append in class python

Tags: python, list, attributes, append

I just want to make a method to append and later edit items in a list, so I have this code:

```
class DataBase:
    lista= []
def nuevo(self,numero):
    self.lista.append(numero)
    print self.lista
Base = DataBase()
while 1:
    destino = input("indique destino: ")
    Base.lista.nuevo(destino)
```

But when I execute it, I have:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'nuevo'
```

Please tell me where I am wrong. I've searched but it looks fine to me.

Comment: *Does* it look fine to you? As the error message is telling you, `Base.lista` is a list (as you specified in the `DataBase` definition), so it doesn't have a `nuevo` method. Did you want `Base.nuevo(destino)`, i.e. calling the method on the instance which adds the item to the list for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you want to append a number to your list which is an property of an instance of `Database` with `nuevo` method. If that's correct, you will need to initialize the `lista` property, then call the nuevo method like below

```
class DataBase:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lista = []
    def nuevo(self,numero):
        self.lista.append(numero)
        print self.lista
Base = DataBase()
while 1:
    destino = input("indique destino: ")
    Base.nuevo(destino)
```